# different attributes other than sandbox to show web page on your site

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a code below that I have sand boxed over and it will not allow user to see the web page I have encoded as its blocked from getting viewed is there any attributes other than "sandbox" that I can use to show a website from a different source into my website

```html
<div style="border: 6px solid #117013; overflow: hidden; margin: 1px auto; max-width: 975px;">
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts"  scrolling="no" src="https://www.chelseafc.com/en/news" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -18px; height: 1250px; margin-top: -559px; width: 680px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already done so

Comment: Short answer is no you can't. If a site sets up frame blocking you can't do anything about it

Comment: is there a way to show another website without using either iframe tags or sandbox attributes

Comment: Not all websites are embeddable with a iframe. For example, an app I worked on has CORS settings pointed to a specific server. I would have to allow access to the server hosting the iframe page as well. There might be other ways, like redirecting to the actual page and injecting some local JS, but that all depends on what you want to do with the 'embedded' page inside your own code and how the 'embedded' page actually works. So no easy shortcuts alas.

Comment: You could write a server-side script similar to a webproxy and serve this from same origin.